# Macro to Copy Row if Highlighted and Concatenate

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet with data I would like to concatenate and use to create an .ini file.

There are multiple columns with data, if a cell in column D is highlighted I want it to copy the data in that row on to another sheet but at the same time I want it to concatenate the data in each column with the column header, see below:

[image: Data Overview]

From the picture above I would like the macro to copy the data into another sheet in the following format:

```
name    = Machine 1

caption = Presentation

make    = Company 1

model   = Model 1
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to create a ini file or a sheet that looks like an ini file?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Andreas - I want to create a sheet that looks like a .ini file so that I can create one from it.

Comment: Genie - I haven't tried any code so far, I am not sure if the concatenate part is achievable, it is outside my knowledge range

Comment: @user3514907 Didn't see your reply until now. If my answer is not what you want then I can delete the answer

Comment: @user3514907 See my updated answer

Comment: Not working for you?

Comment: @Andreas it sort of works but I need the macro to loop through everything highlighted in green and do it for the entire row

Comment: Maybe, just maybe... you did not tell us that? What do you mean with the entire row? As far as the image go, I did.

Comment: @Andrea sorry perhaps my initial question was not clear, I wrote "if a cell in column D is highlighted I want it to copy the data in that row on to another sheet", perhaps it needs re-wording?

Comment: Don't know.. but either way I added an if to the code that checks the interior color if it's "2" or green.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a ini file and not a sheet with ini look. Use this code:

```
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
for i = 3 to LastRow
If range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 2 then
    MyFile = "C:\inifiles\" & Range("C" & i).Value & ".ini" 'Machine 1.ini
    fnum = FreeFile()
    Open MyFile For Output As #fnum
    Print #fnum, "name=" & Range("C" & i).Value
    Print #fnum, "caption=" & Range("D" & i).Value
    Print #fnum, "make=" & Range("E" & i).Value
    Print #fnum, "model=" & Range("F" & i).Value
    Close #fnum
End if
Next i
```

It loops through all rows and uses the data to create a file with the "name" as the name of the file.

EDIT:
If you want to create the sheets with ini look:

```
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 3 To LastRow
If range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 2 then
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    ws.Name = Sheets(1).Range("C" & i).Value
    Sheets(Sheets(1).Range("C" & i).Value).Range("A1") = "name=" & Sheets(1).Range("C" & i).Value
    Sheets(Sheets(1).Range("C" & i).Value).Range("A2") = "caption=" & Sheets(1).Range("D" & i).Value
    Sheets(Sheets(1).Range("C" & i).Value).Range("A3") = "make=" & Sheets(1).Range("E" & i).Value
    Sheets(Sheets(1).Range("C" & i).Value).Range("A4") = "model=" & Sheets(1).Range("F" & i).Value
End if
Next i
```